# Primefaces roweditor in same column with other buttons

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have datatable in which I use roweditor. Everything works fine but I need to add few more buttons in column  in which I have pencil button for editing. That "other" button is always below pencil. I've tried `<p:panelgrid columns="3"...` but when I did that row edithing wasn't possible. I suppose that the problem is with the other two buttons that come with row editing, (`ui-icon-check` and `ui-icon-close`). Can anyone give me an idea? 
Here is my datatable:

```
        <p:dataTable id="sifarnikTable" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
            value="#{attrsBean.listOfDataBeans}" editable="true" 
            selectionMode="multiple" selection="#{attrsBean.selektovani}"
            widgetVar="datatableWidget" var="row" rowKey="#{row.primaryKey}"
            paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} / {totalRecords}"
            emptyMessage="#{messages['datatable.emptymessage']}" rows="15"
            sortMode="multiple" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" 
            filteredValue="#{attrsBean.filteredDatatableList}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                #{resources['db_parametri.title']}
            </f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" />
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" />

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{attrsBean.onEdit}"
                update=":aswdatatable:form:messages, :aswdatatable:form:sifarnikTable, :aswdatatable:form:noviBtn" />

            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{attrsBean.onCancel}"
                update=":aswdatatable:form:messages" />

            <p:columns id="columns" var="column" value="#{attrsBean.columns}" 
                style="#{column.css}" width="#{column.width}"
                sortBy="#{row[column.property]}"
                filterStyle="#{attrsBean.columnCSS}"
                filterBy="#{attrsBean.showFilter==false ? null : row[column.property]}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{row[column.property]}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{row[column.property]}" style="width:96%"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>

            </p:columns>
            <p:column style="width:6px" exportable="false" >                
                <p:rowEditor />
                <div
                    onclick="datatableWidget.unselectAllRows();datatableWidget.selectRow(#{rowIndex}, false);">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">

                                <p:commandLink id="deleteBtn"
                                    onclick="datatableWidget.unselectAllRows();datatableWidget.selectRow(#{rowIndex}, false);brisanjeWidget.show()"
                                    process="@this"
                                    update=":aswdatatable:form:brisanjeDisplay, :aswdatatable:form:sifarnikTable"
                                    styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">

                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{attrsBean.modelForDelete}" value="#{row}" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:outputText value="" />

                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </div>
            </p:column>


        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `style="width: 100%"` attribute of the `<p:column/>`. With that, the column will resize to cater for any additional components. The span of the column can then only be limited by the size of any enclosing container. For example

```
 <h:panelGrid id="theGrid" style="width:200px">
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" id="carList" editable="true">  
        <p:column id="controlColumn" style="width:100%">  
            <p:rowEditor />
            <p:commandButton value="Testing"/>
        </p:column> 
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

In the snippet above, span of `controlColumn` is constrained by the width of `theGrid`

Comment: That doesn't work for me. In my datatable I have `<p:columns>` and after that I have `p:column`. For now ther is only delete Button.

Comment: @miroslav - You didn't post your code here initially, so I answered based on experience. Still, with `width="#{column.width}"`(here you're setting a fixed width) and `style="width:6px"`, you can't expect different results

Comment: Thank you for help anyway. I've decided to use different style solution, and this is not a problem anymore.

Comment: @kolossus I´ve have same problem, the buttons are not in the same level, if you solved, can you post your solution?

Answer (score 2):

In Primefaces 5.x:

```
.ui-row-editor:after {
     clear: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by overriding the css with:

`.ui-row-editor{
    display: inline;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
.ui-row-editor {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Only this worked for me, even though it is now not aligned in the center vertically (this would need more fiddling with the CSS, although in the meantime the UI has changed, so I won't try it)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for me:

```
.ui-row-editor{
    display: inline-block;
}
```