# Align primefaces rowEditor with another element in the same column

Tags: primefaces, datatable, roweditor

I am using PrimeFaces 6. I would like to put a rowEditor and a commandButton besides each other in the same column of a dataTable. However, the elements are rendered one above the other. The layout looks something like this:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    <p:column>  
        ...
    </p:column>
    ...
    <p:column>  
        <p:rowEditor />
        <p:commandButton/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My question is in fact identical to [Primefaces roweditor in same column with other buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17809656/9274948), although the answers are not working for me.

I have tried both

```
.ui-row-editor:after {
    clear: none !important;
}
```

and

```
.ui-row-editor{
    display: inline;
}
```

but this doesn't work. I have inspected the html in the browser inspector and I have no idea why those elements are aligned like that.

Comment: I've added https://stackoverflow.com/a/49365575/880619 to the duplicate you've found. That might work for you..

Comment: @JasperdeVries ofc I am aware of this - I wrote it in the question, although without this question I doubt anyone new would react to the old answer